# Closest and Farthest point on curves of intersection between two ellipsoids to the origin

Tags: geometry, optimization, 3d, lagrange-multiplier, quadrics

A curve is the intersection of two ellipsoids that are given by

$ (r - C_1)^T Q_1 (r - C_1) = 1 $

$ (r - C_2)^T Q_2 (r - C_2) = 1 $

I'd like to find the points on this curve of intersection that are at a minimum/maximum distance from the origin.

**My attempt:**

Building a Lagrange multiplier function

$ g(r , \lambda_1, \lambda_2) = r^T r + \lambda_1 \left( (r - C_1)^T Q_1 (r - C_1) - 1 \right) + \lambda_2 \left( (r - C_2)^T Q_2 (r - C_2) - 1\right) $

it follows that the gradient is

$ \nabla_r g = 2 \bigg(  r + \lambda_1 Q_1 (r - C_1) + \lambda_2 Q_2 (r - C_2) \bigg)  = \mathbb{0}$

In addition to this equation we have the two equations of the two ellipsoids.

There are $5$ unkowns which are the three coordinates of $r$ and $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

That's where I am at.  The task now is to solve these equations for the unknowns.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Following the analysis given in the question, we have the constraint

$ r + \lambda_1 Q_1 (r - C_1) + \lambda_2 Q_2 (r - C_2) ) = 0 $

This is a vector equation, and what it says is that $r$ is a linear combination of $ Q_1 (r - C_1) $ and $ Q_2 (r - C_2) $.

Therefore, the following determinant holds true

$ \begin{vmatrix} r && Q_1 (r - C_1) && Q_2 (r - C_2) \end{vmatrix} = 0 $

or, equivalent

$ r \cdot \bigg( Q_1 (r - C_1)  \times  Q_2 (r - C_2)  \bigg) = 0 $

Combined with $r^T Q_1 r = 1 $ and $r^T Q_2 r = 1 $, these three equations will have a finite number of solutions.  Evaluating $r^T r$ for each we can determine the minimum and the maximum.

I've worked an example in this [Sage worksheet](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVkdFugzAMRd-R-Ie8Na0CxWad1Id8CUITokWbNJY2MEL79bsGylopJo7PiY2U0dzM3Q6V15tR0s02jmqyqq16_zXqoqDSFIzIy1IQ25UkOcoHRPI2sSv9M9rTu1EZFjg22h8feWZoz4f5BtssPe6uFEdePc0cId4Q98kKBOZVomp4gR8HjqNWSKC099VPd3HdWW_RbBfgNYJaKrISS1mrUGvlbuBXnXcBnRpBLc-6tZAHabA0G4Qu5nCuhWDrndeFGpYZRjJaM5ZM_h4iv_i8-rz6_OL7J396lKWez3VKa--67uPi3em37rVMgNAu2Kcn1z_DHLARKIZVWRx17htHfIezLhoyDZsGj6mmYbC7Txc08PYPte-Wag==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

The real solutions are shown at the end of the list of all solutions.